# Creating a laser light in Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I am developing a simulation and need to create a laser light. I have a rectangular actor which serves as the laser unit housing. For the laser itself I am using a spotlight with a light function. The texture for the light function is as follows:[image]

I created a C++ script which I added as a component to the rectangle. In the script I have a couple of UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere) variables, including one for the color of the laser and an AActor* for the spotlight. In the Editor I dragged the spotlight into the AActor slot.

In the BeginPlay() function I tried the following to set the color of the laser:

```
if (LaserLightActor)
{
    USpotLightComponent* SpotLight = Cast<USpotLightComponent>(LaserLightActor);
    if (SpotLight)
    {
        LaserLight->SetLightColor(LaserColor);
    }
    else
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("NO SPOT LIGHT FOUND"));
    }
}
```

But it says "No spot light found". How can I get the spotlight actor in code to be able to set the light color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`USpotLightComponent* SpotLight = Cast<USpotLightComponent>(LaserLightActor);` is the problematic line.

You are casting an `AActor`, which is something that *has* components, directly to a component, which means you expect it to *be* a component, which is never the case.

The approach, instead, should be to get the actor's component. For this, if you know the class of the component ahead of time, and you know there is only one of that type, you can use [`GetComponentByClass`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AActor/GetComponentByClass/1/):

```
USpotLightComponent* SpotLight = LaserLightActor->GetComponentByClass<USpotLightComponent>();
```

There are also other functions to get an actor's component, for different use cases, like: `FindComponentByClass`, `FindComponentByInterface`, `FindComponentByTag`, `GetComponents`, `GetComponentsByTag`, etc.